# Linux distro to learn linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, distribution-choice

Im actually new to all Linux stuff, before I used to have several VMs, where I  used Debian just to see what it actually is.

Now I'm on a long vacation and I thought about picking it up again and try to learn how this OS works, as it will be useful for me on my next college year. I've got 2 simple questions, and as always I don't ask for personal opinions, just for straight facts and knowledge. So:

1. Which Linux distro should I go for, if I want to learn much more about Unix&Linux stuff, I mean during installation, configuration etc. Just looking for a complicated one, the one I will even spend a week or so. Then should I install it on VM or dual boot? (need Windows -> Visual Studio)
2. When I get Raspberry Pi 2, is there a distribution, which fits the best, just works without any problems on this machine?

Comment: For the Raspberry Pi I would suggest Raspbian.

Comment: Also, could you be even more specific in what you are trying to do, what you like/don't like (e.g. graphical vs. text-mode), how recent you want your packages to be…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a complicated distro, **Arch** is the best.

**Reasons**

1. No graphical installation. You'll have to run commands to install it. That includes- **Setting up the partitions, Installing the system, Configuring locales, time etc. , Setting up internet.**
2. During installation, you will be able to "handpick" ackages that you want. This will increase your knowledge about the packages.
3. It's a rolling type distro. That means, you can always keep it updated as soon as a package are upgraded.

Now, for your questions-

1. First install it in VM. See if you can actually manage it or not, especially the installation part. Then if you are confident, install it on your actual machine. You can get an awesome guide [here](http://lifehacker.com/5680453/build-a-killer-customized-arch-linux-installation-and-learn-all-about-linux-in-the-process).
2. I've never tried it on Raspberry. I think it should work fine.